# data.frame and change of variable class R

Tags: r

I´m trying to get a lot of regression coefficients into a dataframe for latex´ing afterwards. However, I´m running into the following problem that I cannot understand after pasting together some values into confidence intervals:

```
> str(q2)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ name     : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ Intercept: Factor w/ 5 levels "15.4533848220452",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ Int.lb   : Factor w/ 5 levels "14.2125590292247",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ Int.ub   : Factor w/ 5 levels "17.1483176230248",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ BAC      : Factor w/ 5 levels "-0.317030740768092",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ Bac.lb   : Factor w/ 5 levels "-0.789518593140102",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ Bac.ub   : Factor w/ 5 levels "0.0844578956839408",..: 1 2 3 4 5
> str(q3)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ CI: Factor w/ 5 levels "(12.17,14.34)",..: 2 1 5 4 3
 $ ci: Factor w/ 5 levels "(-0.31,0.74)",..: 3 5 2 4 1
> q4<-as.data.frame(cbind(name=q2$name,Intercept=q2$Intercept,Interecpt.95.CI=q3$CI,BAC=q2$BAC,BAC.95.CI=q3$ci))
> q4
  name Intercept Interecpt.95.CI BAC BAC.95.CI
1       1         1               2   1         3
2       2         2               1   2         5
3       3         3               5   3         2
4       4         4               4   4         4
5       5         5               3   5         1

> str(q4)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ name        : int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ Intercept      : int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ Interecpt.95.CI: int  2 1 5 4 3
 $ BAC            : int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ BAC.95.CI      : int  3 5 2 4 1
```

I.e. Why did the q4 variables all of a sudden change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is the factors got converted to their internal numeric codes. It happened during the `cbind()` call:

```
R> set.seed(1)
R> dat <- data.frame(A = factor(sample(1:5, 10, rep = TRUE)), 
+                    B = factor(sample(100:200, 10, rep = TRUE)))
R> head(dat)
  A   B
1 2 120
2 2 117
3 3 169
4 5 138
5 2 177
6 5 150
R> str(dat)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ A: Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 2 2 3 5 2 5 5 4 4 1
 $ B: Factor w/ 9 levels "117","120","138",..: 2 1 5 3 7 4 6 9 3 8
R> cbind(name = dat$A, foo = dat$B)
      name foo
 [1,]    2   2
 [2,]    2   1
 [3,]    3   5
 [4,]    5   3
 [5,]    2   7
 [6,]    5   4
 [7,]    5   6
 [8,]    4   9
 [9,]    4   3
[10,]    1   8
```

The reason is that `cbind()` produces a matrix and that is where the conversion happens. It would be easier to create a new data frame in this instance:

```
R> dat2 <- data.frame(name = dat$A, foo = dat$B)
R> dat2
   name foo
1     2 120
2     2 117
3     3 169
4     5 138
5     2 177
6     5 150
7     5 172
8     4 200
9     4 138
10    1 178
```

rather than a `cbind()` followed by an `as.data.frame()` pair of calls.

But the real source of the problem is the numeric data stored as a factor in `q2`. How were these data read in or generated in R? If the were read in to R, why do the end up as a factor? Usually is the data are all numeric in a column R will read in the values as numerics. If there is anything text-like in the data column though, it will get converted to a factor. So I'd try to solve that issue - why were the data in `q2` factors - as it might indicate some issues with reading or generating the data that you are not aware of.

Comment: Thx. The q2 values are from a boot.ci object and for some reason ended up being stored as a factor. The data.frame solution without cbind worked just allright. However what is the convention on when to use as.data.frame with cbind and when to use data.frame??

Comment: @Misha I don't think there is. You are hitting a combination of issues. It is more efficient to just call data.frame() to create the object you want in this case, rather than two calls, especially as the two calls are returning something you don't want.

Comment: There is a convention: NEVER use `cbind` + `as.data.frame`